# can't log in , even after trying to boot through a DVD with downloaded Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

can't log in to my new Dell Laptop "Inspiron" with Ubuntu after an upgrade to  Ubuntu 14.04LTS, so i want to format it, can any body tell how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Burn a DVD/pendirve with the desired Ubuntu distro. Put it in your laptop and reboot. Follow the instructions to perform a fresh installation.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: you will loose all your data if you format partitions.**

Comment: I have no data just started using the laptop after purchase when prompted to upgrade after i got the problem . this is my first time using Ubuntu i think after all will never use it

Comment: what SO do you want to install? I was guessing you want to install Ubuntu...

Comment: i would like to thank logoff who provided the hint to  find the way to resolve my problem, finally i found the right way to prepare a USB flash with the right software and resolved the problem by reinstalling the Ubuntu 14.04 version. i found the right path in this site  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button

Comment: @A.Madanat then vote my answer and/or mark it as the correct one ;)